# Node Selection in XML Document

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am processing an unstructured XML document so that it can be converted to a structured one. The unstructured document looks like the  following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CustomerInformation>
    <CustomerPurchaseID>String</CustomerPurchaseID>
    <MemberAddress>String</MemberAddress>
    <MemberID>String</MemberID>
    <MemberCity>String</MemberCity>
    <MemberName>String</MemberName>
    <MemberType>String</MemberType>
    <MemberState>String</MemberState>
    <MemberSince>String</MemberSince>
    <PurchaseDate>String</PurchaseDate>
    <CreditCardName></CreditCardName>
    <CreditCardExpirration></CreditCardExpirration>
    <Orders>
        <LineItemCode>String</LineItemCode>
        <LineItemID>String</LineItemID>
        <LineItemDescription>String</LineItemDescription>
        <DiscountCode>String</DiscountCode>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
        <LineItemCode>String</LineItemCode>
        <LineItemID>String</LineItemID>
        <LineItemDescription>String</LineItemDescription>
        <DiscountCode>String</DiscountCode>
    </Orders>
    <ShipToAddress>String</ShipToAddress>
    <ShipToCity>String</ShipToCity>
    <ShipToFirstName>String</ShipToFirstName>
    <ShipToLastName>String</ShipToLastName>
    <ShipToState>String</ShipToState>
    <ShipToZIPCode>String</ShipToZIPCode>
    <CustomerAddressLine1>String</CustomerAddressLine1>
    <CustomerAddressLine2>String</CustomerAddressLine2>
    <CustomerID>String</CustomerID>
    <CustomerCity>String</CustomerCity>
    <CustomerEmail>String</CustomerEmail>
    <CustomerFirstName>String</CustomerFirstName>
    <CustomerLastName>String</CustomerLastName>
    <CustomerHomePhone>String</CustomerHomePhone>
    <CustomerState>String</CustomerState>
    <CustomerZIP>String</CustomerZIP>
    <Status>String</Status>
    <OrderedFromName>String</OrderedFromName>
    <CustomerIdentification></CustomerIdentification>
    <PrimaryCustomerIndicator>String</PrimaryCustomerIndicator>
    <OrderedFromAddressLine1Text>String</OrderedFromAddressLine1Text>
    <OrderedFromAddressLine2Text>String</OrderedFromAddressLine2Text>
    <OrderedFromCityName>String</OrderedFromCityName>
    <OrderedFromStateCode>String</OrderedFromStateCode>
    <OrderedFromZip5Code>String</OrderedFromZip5Code>
    <OrderedFromZip4Code>String</OrderedFromZip4Code>
   </CustomerInformation>
```

It is to be converted into something this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlns:evt="http://www.metadata..com/Management/">
    <Identifier>3442=000-MNNN</Identifier>
    <TypeCode>Purchase History</TypeCode>
    <TypeDescription>Order Summary</TypeDescription>
    <PurposeCode>Invoice</PurposeCode>
    <Member>
        <Email>String</Email>
        <MemberSince>03/23/2000</MemberSince>
        <MemberType>
            <MemberShipTypeCode>String</MemberShipTypeCode>
            <TypeDescription>String</TypeDescription>
        </MemberType>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine1Text>String</AddressLine1Text>
            <AddressLine2Text>String</AddressLine2Text>
            <CityName>String</CityName>
            <StateCode>String</StateCode>
            <Zip5Code>String</Zip5Code>
            <Zip4Code>String</Zip4Code>
        </Address>
        <Telephone>
            <AreaCode>String</AreaCode>
            <TelephoneNumber>String</TelephoneNumber>
        </Telephone>
    </Member>
    <Company>
        <CompanyName>String</CompanyName>
        <CustomerIdentification>0.0</CustomerIdentification>
        <PrimaryCustomerIndicator>String</PrimaryCustomerIndicator>
        <CompanyAddress>
            <CompanyAddressLine1Text>String</CompanyAddressLine1Text>
            <CompanyAddressLine2Text>String</CompanyAddressLine2Text>
            <CompanyCityName>String</CompanyCityName>
            <CompanyStateCode>String</CompanyStateCode>
            <CompanyZip5Code>String</CompanyZip5Code>
            <CompanyZip4Code>String</CompanyZip4Code>
        </CompanyAddress>
    </Company>
    <Orders>
     <CreditCard>
            <CardName>String</CardName>
            <CardExpirationDate>1967-08-13</CardExpirationDate>
    </CreditCard>
    <Order>
        <Discount>String</Discount>
        <ShippingVendorName>String</ShippingVendorName>
        <ShipmentTrackingNumber>String</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
        <ShipmentTrackingLinkText>String</ShipmentTrackingLinkText>
        <CustomerName>String</CustomerName>
        <CustomerEmailAddressText>String</CustomerEmailAddressText>
        <Telephone>
            <AreaCode>String</AreaCode>
            <TelephoneNumber>String</TelephoneNumber>
        </Telephone>
        <ShippingAddress>
            <ShippingAddressLine1Text>String</ShippingAddressLine1Text>
            <ShippingAddressLine2Text>String</ShippingAddressLine2Text>
            <ShippingCareOfText>String</ShippingCareOfText>
            <ShippingCityName>String</ShippingCityName>
            <ShippingStateCode>String</ShippingStateCode>
            <ShippingZip5Code>String</ShippingZip5Code>
            <ShippingZip4Code>String</ShippingZip4Code>
        </ShippingAddress>
        <LineItem>
            <LineItemNumber>String</LineItemNumber>
            <LineItemQuantityCount>0</LineItemQuantityCount>
            <ItemOrderedIndicator>String</ItemOrderedIndicator>
            <Discount>String</Discount>
        </LineItem>
    </Order>
    </Orders>
```

I was able to generate the XML by creating the structured format and extracting the related fields by simply using the node values with the XSLT below:

```
<xsl:value-of select=.../>
```

However I felt there might be a better way to do it.  I would like to be able to control the way the structure is generated as I am navigating the unstructured or flat document.  Is there a way to group the elements for all MemberAddress fields for example? If I am able to do that, I can create the Member portion of the output. I could also do the same for the other elements. My concern with hardcoding the structured document is that it may change in the future. I'd prefer to be able to control the output if possible.  All Member information in the source document should be mapped to the Member elements in the target document. The elements in the source document starting with OrderedFrom should be mapped to the Company fields in the target document. The ShipTo elements in turn should be mapped to the shipping information in the orders section of the target document and so on. Please help!!

Comment: `<xmlns:evt="http://www.metadata..com/Management/">` is not a valid start tag. And `<xsl:value-of select=.../>` is not a valid XSLT instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern with hardcoding the structured document is that it may
>   change in the future.

An XSLT stylesheet transforms data from one XML schema to another. It is not realistic to expect that a change in either schema will not necessitate a rewrite of the stylesheet.

> Is there a way to group the elements for all MemberAddress fields for
>   example?

Yes, if you have some way to identify them. For example, you could do:

```
<Member>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Member')]">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name(), 'Member')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Member>
```

to get:

```
<Member>
    <Address>String</Address>
    <ID>String</ID>
    <City>String</City>
    <Name>String</Name>
    <Type>String</Type>
    <State>String</State>
    <Since>String</Since>
</Member>
```

but that doesn't fit your expected output. BTW, your output shows a lot of data that is not in your input, e.g. member's e-mail.

Comment: Yes, the document was trimmed as it is quite verbose, many thanks